# Every time I add a player I need to get the player count

Tags: java, constructor, this

The problem is when I add a new player the count of each player added should increase by 1.
When I try I only get 0

```
public class Player {

    String name;
    static int playerCount=0;
    
    Player(String name){
        this.name=name;
        System.out.println("Player "+name+" added to the team!");
    }
            
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Player one= new Player("x");
        System.out.println("the count now is "+ playerCount);
        
        Player two = new Player("y");
        System.out.println("the count now is "+ playerCount);
        
        Player three = new Player("z");
        System.out.println("the count now is "+ playerCount);
```

Comment: `playerCount` is never increased

Comment: That's right, I am not getting how to increase the player count.

Answer (score 1):

```
 Player(String name){
        this.name=name;
        playerCount = playerCount + 1;
        System.out.println("Player "+name+" added to the team!");
    }
```